# Swift PushViewController From A Different Storyboard

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

---

I'm trying to show one of my `ViewControllers` of a different storyboard programmatically. But for some reasons the properties of the `ViewController` I'm trying to show are nil.

That's my error: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

> I'm getting the error in my `SecondViewController`. It is showing but
>   my app crashes due to the properties being nil.

That's my code:

```
let secondStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let secondViewController = secondStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondVC


self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

That's the code producing the error:

```
class SecondVC: ViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    mapView.isHidden = true // ERROR!! Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

> SOLVED: just had to reconnect my `@IBOutlet` connections

Comment: I know what it means. I just don't know why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the following line is either `nil` or not of type `SecondVC`.

```
secondStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC")
```

I would verify in your storyboard that you have an identifier `secondVC` and that view controller is of type `SecondVC`.

---

**Edit:**

Based on the new code the OP posted in the question, changing the SecondVC to the following should work.

```
class SecondVC: ViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        mapView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Basically this will wait until the view has loaded before accessing the `mapView`. For the original code, you were trying to access `mapView` before it has actually been loaded.

---

**Edit 2:**

It looks like `mapView` outlet is not properly linked to the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think I explained it enough. I edited my question

Comment: @Marie.K I don't understand your edit. `It is showing but my app crashes due to the properties being nil.`.  Which properties are nil? Can you show the line it's actually crashing on?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it again

Comment: @Marie.K Just edited my answer.

Comment: @CharlieFish how OP can run his code in global scope of class? I think problem is not here

Comment: @RobertDresler If you are initializing `mapView` in the storyboard, I don't think there is anyway to run it in the global scope of the class.

Comment: Sorry again. I am doing that already. And if I load this view using a segue it works. But like this from a different storyboard, it doesn't. thank you for being so patient with me

Comment: @Marie.K Have you made sure `mapView` is linked to the outlet in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine I only get the error when trying to show it programmatically from a different storyboard.

Comment: @CharlieFish yes, but you didn't solve the problem. I'm telling you, that is code can't be run in global scope so he probably calls it somewhere else like you do in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @RobertDresler Got it. I was just relying on the OPs original code in the question being what they were actually using.

Comment: @Marie.K But are you able to see this view controller at all? Like does this view controller ever work? And if so, how are you loading it when it works?

Comment: @CharlieFish I think this is just a very common problem with bad connection of `IBOutlet`

Comment: @RobertDresler Yeah that is what it looks like to me too. I commented that above. Really don't see how it can be anything other than that.

Comment: Okay, guys thank you I just disconnected and reconnected my IBOutlet. It works now